# RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant - ActiveAdmin.register Role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

I am using the ActiveAdmin and I have a file doing this:

ActiveAdmin.register Role do
    something---
end

However, my server gives me this error:

```
RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Role
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:461:in `load_missing_constant'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
~/Desktop/Boxfox/app/admin/role.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:424:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:424:in `block in load_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:616:in `new_constants_in'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `load_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require_or_load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:463:in `load_missing_constant'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rolify-3.4.1/lib/rolify/configure.rb:47:in `block in sanity_check'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rolify-3.4.1/lib/rolify/configure.rb:46:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rolify-3.4.1/lib/rolify/configure.rb:46:in `sanity_check'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rolify-3.4.1/lib/rolify/configure.rb:7:in `configure'
~/Desktop/Boxfox/config/initializers/rolify.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 6):

Ah it took me a while to solve this issue:
Go to the directory `app/admin/...`

make sure the file names are in plural not singular, for example:

It should be `videos.rb` NOT `video.rb`

or let's say in your case `roles.rb` not `role.rb`

I found the solution here:
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2334
by @phallstrom